# PHP file_put_contents(x.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, html, permissions

Im currently coding a little project for my school work. It goes like this, i have one index page, you get the option to register classes or students, or view them. When i click register classes, fill out the names and click submit,

> 'file_put_contents(klasse.txt): failed to open stream: Permission
> denied'

but prints out the message that gives after its supposed to be done. I dont know how to fix this, any solutions? Im coding on VSC and using HTML/PHP for this, also im using my school web order to post my coding and thats where i been testing it and getting these results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is probably because the account that the PHP code / webserver runs under doesn't have permission to write to the folder. Remember your webserver runs as a different user than whatever you log in as personally. If you don't control the server and don't have access to set filesystem permissions, speak to the server administrator.

Comment: P.S. You'd be better to store such data in a database anyway. Searching for it again within a file containing lots of registered users is inefficient and fiddly. A SQL query against a database is much easier. Even if you don't have a database server such as MySQL available, you could use a simple file-based database such as SQLite - you'd just need to make sure the sqlite extension is enabled in the PHP setup (but it is, by default, so it's probably there unless anyone specifically changed the setting).

Answer (score 0):

try this ( for unix OS )

```
chmod 750 /path/to/klasse.txt
```

if you are using apache as web server :

```
chown apache:apache /path/to/klasse.txt
```

if not change 750 to 777 (bad recommendation)

Comment: That's assuming the webserver runs a unix-derived O/S, of course. PHP can also run on Windows.

Comment: @ADyson yes for window you can use GUI to change permissions like these : https://www.uwec.edu/kb/article/drives-establishing-windows-file-and-folder-level-permissions/

Comment: I realise that, i just wanted to point it out for anyone else reading. You should probably edit your post with an example for both cases.